# How to perform SIGTRAP emulation with GDB?

Tags: disassembly, gdb

I am trying to analyze a crackme file.

When I open it with `gdb`, I firstly set its `SIGTRAP` handler with, *e.g.*, `int80.SIGTRAP` handler address `0x8011111`.

I caught it through `catch syscall signal` in `gdb`. And, there are some traps in the application, some `int3` interactions.

```
0x80abcde - int3
```

My `gdbinit` file is set like this:

```
b * 0x80abcde
commands 1
call (void)0x8011111(5)
continue
end
```

Is this okay for emulation or do I need to still push the calling address on the stack ?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the *handle* command instead, to pass the signal to the application.
Maybe with something like:

```
handle SIGTRAP nostop print pass
```

GDB will:

- Not stop on SIGTRAP
- Pass it to the application
- Tell you when it get a SIGTRAP

Comment: i have 2 questions also.When i change the handle , how could i stop on my own breakpoints ? HW bps are ok for this ? When i changed the handle like you said , gdb prints "Program terminated with SIGTRAP" , what do you think about this ?